# How can an airfoil create more lift than drag?

Tags: forces, energy-conservation, drag, lift

According to law of conservation of energy, energy can only be converted, not created.

Airfoils convert airspeed to lift, or to put it differently, they create a positive lift force by creating a negative drag force.

To my simplistic understanding, all that should mean, that lift should be <= drag.

Yet, almost all airplaines have lift-to-drag ratios >1. For example, according to Wikipedia, a cruising A380 has a ratio of 20:1.

What is the mistake in my thought process?

Comment: It has more surface area in the direction of lift than it does in the direction of drag.

Answer (score 1):

Lift is at right angles to the motion so ${\bf F}_{\rm lift}\cdot {\bf v}=0$. This  means that  the work done by lift is zero. There is no energy paradaox therefore.

Comment: True, but some energy has to be spent to counter gravity. A non-moving airfoil doesn't generate lift. My assumption (which might be/probably is wrong) is that this is done by moving air particles in the opposite direction of the lift. Equal and opposite force and such.

Comment: A finite-length aerfoil leaves trailing vortices which cost enenrgy and  therefore cause drag, but this has nothing to do with gravity and is not directly related to the lift.  A book on a table is countering gravity by not falling through the table, but it requires no energy just to si tthere.

Comment: Huh, interesting. So to put it in a different way: An airfoil of unlimited size would rest on a cushion of air, not needing to "use up" any energy to create lift. But since a real airfoil ends somewhere, it leaks air there (thus causing the aircraft to fall) and the motion of the aircraft is only necessary to replenish the "leaking" air?

Comment: I'm not sure of the "cushiion of air" idea. The airfoil deflects air downwards, thus giving it momentum in the downward direction. By Newton's third law and equal and opposite upthrust. The airflow changes direction  but not speed, so its energy is unchanged. There is a nice image of the downwash and the wingtip vortices here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21178/how-could-it-be-possible-to-fully-prevent-wing-tip-vortex-formation